# grant only specific IP access to network drive

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hard-drive, remote-access

how to grant a specific IP on my LAN permission to my network drive running on Win7. this machine can't see my ubuntu, and I want only this ubuntu to have access to the drive. so is there any option to give acces only for the specific IP i.e. 192.168.0.xxx ?

I can mount this drive, and I have it already, but now I want to give access only to one machine. I can make password access but can I just specify concrete IP address instead?

Answer (score 1):

Password protection (network authentication) is significantly easier and less error prone.  Password protection also allows you to restrict access per share rather than restricting all access to all shares on the system.

It *can* be done via IPSec, but (at least historically) IPSec on Windows is ridiculously complex and is generally considered a tremendous waste of time for the benefits you get.  I've never seen anybody actually use IPSec before except on production servers.

You can also configure the firewall, but this is only slightly less cumbersome.  Open Control Panel --> System and Security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced Settings.  Make sure Inbound connections are default blocked (this is the default setting).  Then, click on Inbound rules.  Scroll down until you see "File and Printer Sharing".  The ones that *should* do what you want are NB-Datagram-In, NB-Name-In, NB-Session-In, and SMB-In.  I don't believe the others are used for file sharing.  For each of those, double click the rule to open the Properties Window.  On the Scope tab, add the IP Address in question to the list of allowed clients.  This *should* prohibit any other IP from accessing all file shares on this computer, but you should test it.

Comment: thanks for reply. what about "computers" tab in these rules properties? "allow connection only from these computers" sounds also (!) like this what I am looking for... this is beauty of windows: many options that sounds exactly like this what you want: just trial end error and hopes for the best

Comment: The Computers tab allows you to enter host names, but it will only work if both endpoints can use Microsoft's secure/trusted connection methods.  That means Vista or later, typically, although I'm not sure how Home versions are restricted for that.  Additionally, the computers have to trust each other.  That means they have to be getting their identity certificates from a CA that's trusted by both computers (in practice, typically a domain controller) or you must manually install the certificates that verify identity on BOTH computers.